# iPhone navigation controller but with different detail views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

so i need to build an app similar in structure to the settings app, a navigation table view that then moves into a detail view, but each detail view has to be a different nib file. I can find anyway to do it.

Comment: Have you tried reading the iPhone reference guides? They are very good and what you're asking for is relatively simple - users on SO aren't going to just write the code for you so its worth reading up on. Start with navigation controllers and then move onto UITableViewControllers. Once you understand both of them, start playing with NIB files for the pages you want to go through too... (obviously the order in which you do this doesn't matter here, just don't try too much at once)

Comment: Yeah i have tried the guides but cant seem to find any way to load multiple .xib files. I'm using an array to load in the number of rows and textLable.text for each row, so can u use that array to load in the different nib names into initWithNibName?

Comment: I'm willing to pay if u can help me out with this, i know u said it's easy. but i'm wasting too much time trying to get through it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest code sample that I can recall is from **Beginning iPhone 3 Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK** by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche. Its Chapter 9 (Navigation
Controllers and Table Views) is pretty much what you need.

I think they have made the book's code sample free to download (if not, please correct me). This is the link http://iphonedevbook.com/forum/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've just been doing that in an app I'm developing. It's pretty easy. When the user selects something (say touching a table cell in the current view) then you just use the pushViewController:animated: method on your navigation controller. So you'd do it something like this:

```
 // User requested switch

 MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController..... // Setup as neccessary

 [myVC setThingToLookAt:someThing]                // So the right data is shown

 [myNavigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES]; // Shows the new view
```

When the user is done, you can pop the view back off when you leave the detail view

```
 [myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The [NavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) section of the UIViewController documentation is helpful in all this. It's actually a pretty easy thing to do.